# Encode JWT (JSON web token) on Arduino

Tags: arduino, jwt, service-accounts, rs256

I've been trying to encode a JWT using RS256 (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) on Arduino (ESP32) to get the access token from Google's service account, but the methods I found don't work.

I've tried to hash and then encode, but I can't find any library for encoding, and I wouldn't say I like to write the whole function myself. Then I found several JWT libraries, but they all didn't support RS256 algorithm. [Here's one of the library](https://github.com/Ant2000/CustomJWT)

I would like to know if anyone knows how to encode with RS256 and generate the JWT on Arduino, thanks!